Do you say he can improve or he can improves and why
Do you put improve or improves for the sentence above and why would you use that?

Hello Mia.  It is a good idea to check your textbook, as this topic is explained in every English textbook that teaches the word "can".

He can improve. (Not improves)
The key here is the word can, which is an example of a modal verb. There are many grammar articles online about modal verbs, so I'd encourage you to start there if you're not sure. But the basic principle is:

Modal verb + second verb in its bare infinitive form.


He can go to school today (not goes)
He can understand how modal verbs work! (not understands)
After two years studying he can now speak French quite well. (not speaks)

